# Ubuntu logs something and it becomes impossible to open os again

Tags: root, disk-usage, logs

I had ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my laptop with 50 gb root 20 gb swap and 160 gb home directories. After I started the computer it started to log something and gave me the warning root part is full I checked and the root files were full I deleted Kern* and messages* and system log files however it kept creating them after I restarted the computer it started to give error something with physical disk I could not read cuz it goes too fast. And I thought that is about the version and installed 18.04 but same happened I could not open the root file and don't know what was the reason for that currently I cannot use my os  ecause of the same error. If anyone saw that and fix it please help me. Laptop model: Asus vm590u

Comment: So read the logs and post any errors.....

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! An error regarding "physical disk" indicates the possibility of failing hardware. You may find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) useful. Your problem is highly unlikely to be  version related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more installations I saw the log file the error is device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000 and it keeps logging it. 
The solution for that can be found here: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Error-Spam-AER-id-00e5-PCIe-Bus-Error-severity-Corrected/td-p/5933687
But be quick give your root space like 50gb area so it won't be filled out immediately. Then make the changes on the link.